# Getting unexpected results in API Gateway from cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am somewhat new to writing yaml files and deploying them. I have one built from things that I have worked on in the past, but it is producing results that I don't understand and I believe that this is causing a CORS error when I used the API Gateway (It works using insomnia/postman).

Here is the YAML file.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Storygraf backend API

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    
Resources:
  ExpressApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: prod
      StageName: dev

  ExpressLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Environment:
        Variables:

      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: lambda.handler
      MemorySize: 512
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        ProxyApiRoot:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ExpressApi
            Path: /
            Method: ANY
            cors: true
        ProxyApiGreedy:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ExpressApi
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
            cors: true
```

I don't really understand the ProxyAPIRoot and ProxyAPIGreedy settings, but I have run the deployment with and without that section and gotten the same results.

I am also attempting to create two stages on the API gateway - one for production and one for development but it occurs to me that I don't really understand the stages very well and the result that I am getting has a "dev" stage (which is correct) and a "Stage" stage, which is not correct.

Here are the resources and stages for the resulting gateway.

Why is there are "Stage" stage and not a "prod" stage?
What is the proxy? Is it causing my CORS problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create separate SAM YAML files for different environments. You cannot specify two stages in the same YAML file. If you want to deploy the complete stack in one YAML file, I suggest you switch to pure Cloudformation template, then you would have a lot more flexibility on defining resources.

You can checkout this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-stage.html) and create multiple stages.

Regarding the /{proxy+} resource, it will capture all the requests, like /products, /users/1. Whereas, the / resource will only respond to requests to the endpoint root url, i.e / only.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. So, what is the separate "Stage" stage that is created?

Comment: I am not really sure of that. It could have been created during a previous deployment. Can you check cloudformation and list all the events, that took place during the deployment of your SAM app. In the background, the SAM template gets converted to Cloudformation, so you should see the list of events that took place.

Comment: I was under the impression that sam / cloud formation would destroy previous builds and create new ones - so that anything done in a previous build would be undone? If  not, then that is likely what happened.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but sometimes, it fails to destroy some things. I have faced this issue when I used SAM. I am not sure, but if you could post a screenshot of the deployment events, it would be helpful to debug. Also, did you create any stage from the console? That could be it. Otherwise, I could not think of anything which created the separate 'Stage' stage.